# How to prevent element from being blended/hardware accelerated

Tags: css, webkit, hardware-acceleration

In CSS, you can force an element to always be hardware accelerated by applying a property like:

```
-webkit-translate: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

Is it possible to do the opposite? Apply a property that will make sure that item is never blended?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? I ask only out of curiosity :-)

Comment: Translating an element causes all other elements on that same z-index to redraw. This can have pretty big performance implications if you have a large page (that goes offscreen). In some cases it is okay to move the element up to a different z-index but I have hit a scenario where that isn't possible. It'd be nice to just say "don't draw these duders"

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a way to prevent it. But instead of using a translate3d, you could just do a plain translate which would not be hardware accelerated.

```
transform: translate(10px,10px)
```